# Can't ignore all files except *.m in directories

Tags: regex, mercurial, hgignore

I want Mercurial to automatically ignore all files not ending in '.m' at the repo root and in all subdirectories, and I can't make this work.

Here's a dummy repo (no files tracked):

```
./.hgignore
./foo/abcdef.m
./foo/abcdef.txt
./abcdef.m
./abcdef.txt
```

This is .hgignore:

```
syntax: regexp
re:.*[^m]$
```

And this is what happens:

```
~/src/dummy$ hg st -A
? abcdef.m
I .hgignore
I abcdef.txt
I foo/abcdef.m
I foo/abcdef.txt
```

That is, abcdef.txt and foo/abcdef.txt are ignored, but so is foo/abcdef.m, which shouldn't be.

If I change my regex to the opposite:

```
syntax: regexp
re:.*[m]$
```

I get the expected result:

```
~/src/dummy$ hg st -A
? .hgignore
? abcdef.txt
? foo/abcdef.txt
I abcdef.m
I foo/abcdef.m
```

The .m files are ignored, the .txt files are not.

What am I doing wrong? Why does an inclusive regex (ends in 'm') work but not an exclusive  regex (doesn't end in 'm')?

Mercurial 2.8.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Your regex is excluding the "foo" directory, and thereby "foo/abcdef.m". Not sure how to best fix it.

Comment: Can you try "rooting" your regexp to the beginning of the string?  If this works (I don't have mercurial to test), I can add an answer with explanation: `re:^.*[^m]$`

Comment: No, the problem seems to be that there's no way to match only filenames and not directory names. I guess this problem is unsolvable :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a specified limitation, you cannot **exclude all but**... You can read it [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/.hgignore):

> **Limitations**
>
> There is no straightforward way to ignore all but a set of files.
>   Attempting to use an inverted regex match will fail when combined with
>   other patterns. This is an intentional limitation, as alternate
>   formats were all considered far too likely to confuse users to be
>   worth the additional flexibility.

And @sth is right here, you are blocking `foo` sub-folder entirely in your first attempt.

Comment: That's a truly horrific limitation! Is there really no extension to cope with this?